# How to camera match move for moon/clouds/stars?

Tags: after-effects, davinci-resolve, greenscreen, chromakey, visual-effects

I have found the way to replace green screen and match camera move with background footage, but I don't understand how is it done for sky because the markers on green screen moves way faster than the objects in sky. Please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assume celestial bodies are infinitely far away, as the amount of parallax you can achieve in anything except a space ship is infinitesimal. So that means that the moon and stars stay fixed to a point of view, as long as you're not panning. If you're panning then the moon and stars can be on layers a long way from the camera, but scaled up to fill the frame.